# Mongoose: find by slug $or id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, routes, slug

i'm trying to route /:slug and the user can type the _id or a slug generated by slugify.

i'm trying this on the route controller:

```
const query = await Tour.find({
  $or: [{ _id: req.params.slug }, { slug: req.params.slug }]
});
```

but it doesn't work, i only manage to make it work when i do this:

```
 if (req.params.slug.includes('-')) {
  query = await Tour.find({ slug: req.params.slug });
} else {
  query = await Tour.findById(req.params.slug);
}
```

the question is: what am i doing wrong using $or operator? thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825031/mongoose-query-or-slug-id - It might help!

Answer (score 3):

I have been struggling with the same implementation.

To make it work:

```
// Add this line
const { Types, isValidObjectId } = require('mongoose')

// Just placing slug on a const for readability
const { slug } = req.params 

// Change the query to:
const query = await Tour.find({
  $or: [
    { _id: isValidObjectId(slug) ? Types.ObjectId(slug) : undefined },
    { slug }
  ]
});
```

The trick here was to query the id like `{ _id: Types.ObjectId(slug) }`, but the thing is if `slug` is actually a slug and not an ObjectId, `Types.ObjectId(slug)` will break the code. So it's important to make a check using `isValidObjectId`.

I got this tip from a Mongoose warning and through many answers here:

> (node:13749) [MONGOOSE] Warning: mongoose: To create a new ObjectId please try `Mongoose.Types.ObjectId` instead of using `Mongoose.Schema.ObjectId`.